# I can't use 'click' to add short cut in android studio?

Tags: macos, android-studio

[add shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9FL9.png)

I use command + button Click nothing happened but every other keys work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the settings menu as described below
 File ->
 Settings... ->
  Keymap

From the appropriate menu/sub menu header, Pick the action you want to assign a shortcut to.
Right click to select either  a keyboard or mouse shortcut.

**Keyboard shortcut**

Choose a key combination. 
If the key combination is already in use you can either choose a second stroke or a modifier like CTRL, ALT or SHIFT etc.

**Mouse shortcut**

Choose a click or double click, scroll wheel up / down etc.
If the mouse short cut combination is already in use you can use a keyboard modifier like CTRL, ALT or SHIFT etc.

Comment: I told I wanna add shortcut with mouse click and it does't work .